# how to outer merge multiple csv files (list) and append it to a new column

Tags: python, csv

I've been trying to merge multiple .csv files together and I want to end up with the unique code, value1, value2, value3.
I have tried:

```
set_a = list1
set_b = list2
new = set_a & set b
```

but I need the null values to show up and have all the unique codes from the main list. I am also having a tough time appending the values from another csv file to another column. I like to have:

```
List_1 = [(1234, abcd), (5678, efgh), (9101112, ijkl)]
List_2 = [(1234, abcd, Y), (9101112,ijkl, Y)]
List_3 = [(5678, efgh), (9101112, ijkl)]

output = [(1234, abcd, Y, null), (5678, efgh, null, Y), (9101112, ijkl, Y, Y]
```

Comment: You almost certainly want to look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) for this, especially if you want it to work like SQL joins.

Comment: I've been having a tough time installing pandas in pycharm so I was hoping to do it without pandas

Comment: Shouldn't  your output have `(9101112, ijkl, Y, null)` instead of `(9101112, ijkl, Y, Y)` as there is no 'Y' in List_3 or am I missing something here?